# Is there any detailed video lecture series which uses “Compilers: Principles, Techniques and Tools” by Aho et al as the text book as a bible?

Tags: self-learning, resource-request, compiling

I am interested in learning *Compiler Design* , and from many resources I came to know that "The Dragon Book" is a good textbook. (Below are the two editions of the said textbook. [Red Dragon and Purple Dragon])

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image: Red Dragon Book]

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$*Compilers: Principles, Techniques and Tools (Red Dragon)*

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image: Purple Dragon]

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$*Compilers: Principles, Techniques and Tools (Purple Dragon)*

I am following the Red Dragon book currently, because it is a bit thinner and plan to cover the most important concepts from the Red Dragon and then move to the Purple Dragon to cover the possible extra topics introduced due to modern advancements.

But since I am doing self-study, it is at times hard to understand the material without proper guidance.

So if anyone knows about any video lecture series on Compiler Design which uses any of the above said text for reference, then it will be quite helpful to me (though I prefer a video lecture series based on the Red Dragon, but begin an old book, it might be difficult to find such a lecture series). It would be like taking an actual course, getting input from the instructor, and then improvising on the learning thereafter by reading the text.

Being a self-learner, I am having a bit of difficulty in understanding a few concepts.

[A rough look of the contents of the two books shows that:

$\text{Content$_{purple} \cap$ Content$_{red}$ = A substantial amount of the core compiler concepts}$,

so if a video lecture series for any one of the above texts is provided I shall use it accordingly (i.e. watch the portions pertaining to the Red Dragon first, if the lecture series is based on the purple book)]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

---

My main problem is that I find it difficult to get the concepts directly by reading it from the book for the first time, face difficulty in understanding the proofs on my own, unless someone pictorially explains me the concepts in a step by step manner (be it a proof of a theorem , or some concept, or terminology etc.) Indeed a professor makes the subject easier for a student to understand...

Please help me.

Comment: Note that this isn't the current edition of the book, though for  first course (everywhere but Stanford, perhaps) it is more than enough. You might be better off finding a local person who knows about compilers and language principles and ask them the questions you have.

Comment: You might also want to get a copy of Sethi's language principles book and go through it first. It will give you some good background. https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Languages-Concepts-Constructs-2nd/dp/0201590654. I've taught out of both book, but the Languages book/course was a prerequisite for the compiler course.

Comment: @Buffy finding a local person at my place who knows compiler and language principles to ask him my questions is an ordeal with the added pandemic situation...:(